# Bootstrap Carousel and Google Maps and Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: php, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, advanced-custom-fields

I'm building a wordpress site (here: http://dev.tps.entropii.com/contact-us/) that requires a full page width google map on the contact page. The Business has two addresses so they effectively need two maps with a means to switch between them. I'm using Advanced Custom Fields plugin to give the user the functionality to update/edit their addresses.

Here's the problem. In order to give the functionality to switch back and forth between the two maps I decided to put them inside a twitter bootstrap carousel. One slide for each map. This works as expected with one problem. The map that is contained within the inactive slide (e.g. the slide that doesn't have the class 'active' on page load), doesn't seem to fully load. If I put the maps side by side on the page without the carousel they load no problem.

Because I'm using advanced custom fields, the maps are being loaded using php. Here's the HTML/php from my template file:

`

```
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
    <!-- map 1 -->
    <?php $map1 = get_field('map_1'); if( !empty($map1) ): ?>
        <div class="acf-map" id="map1">
            <div class="marker" data-lat="<?php echo $map1['lat']; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $map1['lng']; ?>"></div>
        </div>
   <?php endif; ?>
   </div>

    <div class="item">
    <!-- map 2 -->
    <?php $map2 = get_field('map_2'); if( !empty($map2) ): ?>
        <div class="acf-map" id="map2">
           <div class="marker" data-lat="<?php echo $map2['lat']; ?>" data-lng="<?php echo $map2['lng']; ?>"></div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#map-carousel" data-slide="prev"></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#map-carousel" data-slide="next"></a>
</div>`
```

My suspicion is that because the inactive slides of the bootstrap carousel are set to display none, that the content isn't being loaded int he first place properly. However I'm completely stabbing in the dark. Can anyone shed any light on this?

Let me know if you ned any more info. Thanks,

Comment: change the javascript code to use visibility: hidden instead of display:none

Comment: Thanks! Actually applied in the css:

`
    .carousel-inner>.item {
        display: block; 
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .carousel-inner>.active {
        visibility:visible;
    }
`

That solves the load problem but causes slides to stack.  Trying to figure out how to get them to positioned correctly now that we're not using display none.

Comment: Have added: .carousel-inner>.item {
    display: block; 
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0;
}

.carousel-inner>.active {
    visibility: visible;
    height: auto;
}

This kinda works but causes the slides to 'snap' abruptly into appearance instead of sliding in. Not ideal.

Comment: google map need fix height and width for rendering. fix means 300px, not percentage. display: none cause the div to be 0px 0px thats why it is not rendering correctly.